# подскажите как в область иконки своего плагина браузера вывести текст?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

подскажите как в область иконки своего плагина браузера вывести текст?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: "Текст" });
```

Узнать подробнее об этом можно здесь для мозилы: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText
и здесь для гугла:https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/reference/browserAction?hl=ru